how to perform actions after (nested) Job Chain
I have a job, that chains some other jobs like this:
class MasterJob implements ShouldQueue
{

    public function handle(): void  
    {
        Bus::chain([
            new JobOne(),
            new JobTwo(),
            new JobThree(),
        ])->dispatch();
    }
}

In an usecase I have to chain this MasterJob with a function like this:
Bus::chain([
    new MasterJob(),
    function () {
        //jobs done - do some things ...
    }
]);

This is not working as intended, the MasterJob gets queued and the function executes.
How can I accomplish that the function gets executed after all jobes are done?
Laravel 11.29.0

You didn't specify your laravel version; Therefore here the most recent documentation which hints you a solution imo: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#adding-jobs-to-the-chain

its 11.29.0. I do not want to add an additional job but execute some code after all chained jobs are done. The special case is, that a job starts a job chain.

There is event class called BusDispatched. Maybe you can try to link a listener to it.

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#dispatching-batches
then() probably is what you're looking for.

then() is only available in batches not in chains

your code *should work. what is your default queue? Does your MasterJob specify some custom queue connection?

@krisgjika it works in a test, but not "live", as all jobs get queued. The chained MasterJobs seems to be handled as "done" as soon as all child jobs are queued and the chained function gets called.
the setup has nothing special. no custom queue.
